# How can I model exponential sawtooth like regression?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have this type of data. It is the occupancy rate of a hotel in January. Each line is one of the years (2019-2023). So in January occupancy rate is lets say X rooms. I know that in December it was 180 and in November it was 150 etc. I want to forecast 2024 January occupancy rate-X, based on occupancy rate of January in last 5 years as well as build up to those rates in the previous 6 month.

[image]

If I plot this as a timeseries, it will look like this [graph](https://www.cameroncarson.com/expressions/sawtooth-exponential-wave).

I searched online for papers on how to model this but was not able to find anything.